# Linux fifo (named pipe) O_NONBLOCK breaks pipe

Tags: linux, posix, pipe, fifo

I've been writing a small program in C++ for linux using inter process communication. I had a problem when trying to read in a non-blocking way with one process and write (blocking) with another process. The issue looks like this, when the parent tries to read the pipe with `O_NONBLOCK` (or `O_NDELAY`) it never reads a single byte and when the child tries to write on the pipe, it fails and the `SIGPIPE` broken pipe signal is sent. Here is an example of the code:

```
// Parent process
mkfifo(PROC_COPROC, 0666);

int fd_co = open(PROC_COPROC, O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY);
char c;
int n;
fcntl(fd_co,F_SETFL,0); //fix it
while ((n = read(fd_co, &c, 1)) > 0)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}
close(fd_co);

// Child process
int fd = open(PROC_COPROC, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
if ( fd != -1 ) 
{
    write( fd , "message\n" , 8); //Fails here if flag not set
}
else
    printf("Ne peut pas ecrire sur le fifo\n");
close(fd);
```

I finally found a way to resolve this by using `fcntl(fd_co,F_SETFL,0);` right after the non-blocking open call.

After reading the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl), I couldn't find any (simple) explanation why I sould reset the file descriptor's flag if I want to read non-blocking and write blocking.

Anyone has an explanation or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure both ends of the pipe are open (reading and writing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" with O_NDELAY is, that read returns `-1` and sets errno to `EAGAIN`, when there's no data available. So, you must test the return value of `read` for `-1` and errno and then read again.

Your "fix" just resets O_NDELAY, which makes read block again, if there's nothing to read from the FIFO.

See also [`read`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html)

> **RETURN VALUE**
>   ... On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
>
> **ERRORS**
>    **EAGAIN** The file descriptor fd refers to a file other than a socket and has
>                 been marked nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read would block.
>   **EAGAIN** or **EWOULDBLOCK**
>                 The file descriptor fd refers to a socket and has been marked
>                 nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read would block.  POSIX.1-2001
>                 allows either error to be returned for this case, and does not require
>                 these constants to have the same value, so a portable application
>                 should check for both possibilities.

You might also consider using [`select`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html), or [`poll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) as @BasileStarynkevitch suggested, if blocking is a problem in your case.

Comment: I suggest using `poll` instead of `select`

Comment: You are right, I missed that detail. Since the reading is made in a loop, I fixed it by opening the file descriptor read only | noblock before the loop and close it after. This way the read end is opened and it will read as soon as the write end opens and starts sending data. Thanks!